# Excel VBA - Check whether a filtered table returns any results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that filters a table (in the code as a ListObject) and then copies the visible cells in the DataBodyRange to a seperate table. The code works fine unless the filtering action removes all the data (i.e. the table only has the header row and nothing else).

Is there a neat way to check whether any rows are visible? I'd like to avoid `on error resume` terms if possible, I'm struggling to think of any other way though?

I've included some pseudocode below to illustrate what I mean, any assistance would be much appreciated!

Adam

```
If TargetTable.DataBodyRange.VisibleRows.Count > 0 Then
    TargetTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=OutputPasteRange
End If
```

Comment: You're getting a 1004 error when trying to access the `TargetTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` range, right?

Answer (score 6):

Use the Table's `Range` object, not the `DataBodyRange`.  Then, check to make sure that `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1`.

```
Sub TestEmptyTable()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim outputPasteRange As Range
Dim tblIsVisible As Boolean

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
Set outputPasteRange = Range("B15")

If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count > 1 Then
    tblIsVisible = True
Else:
    tblIsVisible = tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1
End If

If tblIsVisible Then
    tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=outputPasteRange

Else:
    MsgBox tbl.Name & " has been filtered to no visible records", vbInformation

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: doesn't work, I checked it too!! put some filtering which left few records and check...

Comment: Should be > 1, not >=1... Just revised!

Comment: That returns only 2 values: 1 or ListObject total rows. And 1 is in situation when you have few filtering results... That was my way of thinking, too, but not working.... :)

Comment: I'd like to see it because I really have `tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count ` returning 1 if filtering giving 6 rows visible... (Excel 2010) Any bug?

Comment: Please review screenshots.

Comment: @KazJaw I think I know what you are doing and also how to handle it. I will revise momentarily...

Comment: I think I know where is the bug. Put your filtering in column different to First and you will have visible results and msgbox too

Comment: that is what I notice, too!

Comment: @KazJaw try now. I add handling for multiple `.Areas` in `tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.  If there are multiple areas, then we know the filter leaves some visible results. If there is only 1 `.Area` then we must submit to boolean test.

Comment: @KazJaw same thing happens with `.AutoFilter` that's where I've seen this behavior before :)

Answer (score 5):

Just check if the `Range.Height` is not 0:

```
If [Table1].Height Then
```

Also, `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is not needed when the `.Height` is more than 0:

```
If TargetTable.DataBodyRange.Height Then TargetTable.DataBodyRange.Copy OutputPasteRange
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach would be to compare `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address` to the header row address, `tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address`.

Here is a variation of David's code:

```
Sub TestEmptyTable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim outputPasteRange As Range
    Dim tblIsVisible As Boolean

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set outputPasteRange = Range("B15")

    tblIsVisible = tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address <> _ 
        tbl.HeaderRowRange.Address

    If tblIsVisible Then
        tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            Destination:=outputPasteRange
    Else
        MsgBox tbl.Name & " has been filtered to no visible records", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```